# PHP on IIS 10 , site running slow

Tags: windows, php, iis, wordpress, php-cgi

I have IIS 10 running on windows server 2022, wordpress website running php is setup on iis. Everything was working fine until we decided to upgrade php from 7.4 to 8.0. now the website is painfully slow. It takes 10-20 seconds to load first page and then even more for other pages.
I am responsible for maintaining infrastructure not for website maintenance. I am beginner in this setup, tried multiple things still couldn't get it to work.
I managed to get CPU processing to low by lowering worker processes. but traffic being received is somewhat still high.
Does anyone have any fixes for this?

Comment: Definitely shouldn't be doing that. I would try creating a second vhost and testing a standard website of some kind that is known to work right on php8. It is possible that the php version change broke the programming logic of the wordpress version you're trying to use. Did you also upgrade wordpress to a version that is known to be compatible with php8? If you're pressed for time, roll back to 7.4 and debug during off-hours.

Comment: Honestly, stop using PHP and WordPress on Windows.  It's horrible and there is little support around for it, so it's hard to get help when you need it.  Is everything you are using (WordPress and plugins) compatible with PHP 8?  Have you checked the PHP error logs?  Who is responsible for website maintenance, because this is a website problem, most likely in IIS.

Comment: Check your PHP Setup. You want the `VS16 x64 Non Thread Safe` Edition. TS may load php files painfully slow in some setups.